# File changed watcher Tool

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I have recently begun a new project which runs on remote computer. I usually remote debug the application. I have setup microsoft sync toy to "echo" the built exe,dll,pdb and configs to the remote computer.

However, i cant add synctoy to my visual studio build events because it might disturb some of the other programmers in my team. I was wondering, which (free) tool would you guys use to watch a folder of files and kick off synctoy when a change is detected.

I can write a simple file watcher, but rather than reinvent the wheel, i would rather just use an existing tool. Searching on google yields so many tools, i wouldn't want to try them out just to find a good one.

Comment: The only xcopy i know is the xcopy.exe which copies files and doesnt watch for changes before copying.

Comment: Right, the only reason I mentioned it was because you mentioned adding SyncToy to your build events, which led me to believe that the build would trigger the sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may fall under the banner of reinventing the wheel, but if you are using .NET, the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class, albeit without a UI, is pretty much as comprehensive as you can get, out of the box.

I'm sure you could knock something up with it in a very short time.

Comment: after a while of looking around, i just wrote my own watcher because its just simpler to write my own tool.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Robocopy with the /MON or /MOT options?  See http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html for more details.

Comment: Robocopy only watches for file changes once per minute, making it quite unusable for this kind of thing.